# how to get the values inside a frame?

Tags: html, firebug, greasemonkey

body --> div --> frame --> body --> form --> table. Need the values inside the tables.

I am using the childNode method but do not get any childNode beyond the frame.

```
                <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
                <div id="content-loader-load" class="content-wrapper">
                <h2 id="page-title-home-link" style="display:none">
                <h1 id="page-title">Case Detail - 1186</h1>
                <iframe id="iframe" frameborder="0" style="border: 0px none; width: 100%; height: 1280px; margin-top: 20px;" src="case_detail.php3?ticket_num=1186">
                <html>
                <head>
                <body>
                <iframe id="PopupNote_IFrameHostInfoNote" frameborder="0" src="/PopupNoteContents.php?sNote=&bNoteIsURL=0&sType=Info&sHeading=Note&bAllowMove=0&id=PopupNote_IFrameHostInfoNote" scrolling="no" style="display:none; padding : -1em; border: 0px outset #000000; z-index:9999;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:262px;">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                <table id="CSPageHeader" width="100%" border="0" style="display: none;">
                <p> </p>
                <form id="ticket_detail" method="post" name="ticket_detail">
                <input type="hidden" value="0" name="deleteLock">
                <input type="hidden" value="" name="mode">
                <input type="hidden" value="desc" name="sort">
                <input type="hidden" value="d6761ab1fbf9aafd71059ff046d74203" name="SessionKey">
                <input id="include_files" type="hidden" value="0" name="include_files">
                <input id="work_timer_flag" type="hidden" value="0">
                <input id="ticket_num" type="hidden" value="1186" name="ticket_num">
                <input id="1186_old_status" type="hidden" value="11" name="1186_old_status">
                <input id="new_status" type="hidden" value="11" name="new_status">
                <input id="1186_old_cause_code" type="hidden" value="" name="1186_old_cause_code">
                <input id="new_cause_code" type="hidden" value="" name="new_cause_code">
                <input type="hidden" value="on" name="old_notify_radio">
                <input id="1186_old_case_severity_id" type="hidden" value="3" name="1186_old_case_severity_id">
                <input id="new_case_severity_id" type="hidden" value="3" name="new_case_severity_id">
                <input id="1186_old_priority" type="hidden" value="3" name="1186_old_priority">
                <input id="new_priority" type="hidden" value="3" name="new_priority">
                <input id="1186_old_category_str" type="hidden" value="1" name="1186_old_category_str">
                <input id="category_str" type="hidden" value="1" name="category_str">
                <input id="new_category_str" type="hidden" value="1" name="new_category_str">
                <input id="1186_old_assigned" type="hidden" value="370" name="1186_old_assigned">
                <input id="new_assigned" type="hidden" value="370" name="new_assigned">
                <input id="1186_old_workflow" type="hidden" value="0" name="1186_old_workflow">
                <input id="new_workflow" type="hidden" value="0" name="new_workflow">
                <input id="1186_old_vendor_tkt" type="hidden" value="" name="1186_old_vendor_tkt">
                <input id="new_vendor_tkt" type="hidden" value="" name="new_vendor_tkt">
                <input id="1186_old_notify_value" type="hidden" value="on" name="1186_old_notify_value">
                <input id="1186_old_visible_description" type="hidden" value="test case" name="1186_old_visible_description">
                <input id="new_visible_description" type="hidden" value="test case" name="new_visible_description">
                <input id="1186_old_ticket_type_id" type="hidden" value="1" name="1186_old_ticket_type_id">
                <input id="new_ticket_type_id" type="hidden" value="1" name="new_ticket_type_id">
                <input id="1186_old_netlog_tt_number" type="hidden" value="" name="1186_old_netlog_tt_number">
                <input id="new_netlog_tt_number" type="hidden" value="" name="new_netlog_tt_number">
                <input id="1186_old_netlog_carrier_id" type="hidden" value="0" name="1186_old_netlog_carrier_id">
                <input id="new_netlog_carrier_id" type="hidden" value="0" name="new_netlog_carrier_id">
                <input id="1186_old_netlog_carrier_ticket" type="hidden" value="" name="1186_old_netlog_carrier_ticket">
                <input id="new_netlog_carrier_ticket" type="hidden" value="" name="new_netlog_carrier_ticket">
                <input id="1186_old_netlog_resolution_id" type="hidden" value="0" name="1186_old_netlog_resolution_id">
                <input id="new_netlog_resolution_id" type="hidden" value="0" name="new_netlog_resolution_id">
                <input id="1186_old_remote_ticket_num" type="hidden" value="0" name="1186_old_remote_ticket_num">
                <input id="new_remote_ticket_num" type="hidden" value="0" name="new_remote_ticket_num">
                <input id="1186_old_remote_server_info_id" type="hidden" value="0" name="1186_old_remote_server_info_id">
                <input id="new_remote_server_info_id" type="hidden" value="0" name="new_remote_server_info_id">
                <input id="1186_old_responsible_party" type="hidden" value="" name="1186_old_responsible_party">
                <input id="new_responsible_party" type="hidden" value="-1" name="new_responsible_party">
                <input id="1186_old_resolution_code" type="hidden" value="" name="1186_old_resolution_code">
                <input id="new_resolution_code" type="hidden" value="-1" name="new_resolution_code">
                <table class="table" cellpadding="4" border="1">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td class="TableFormLabel">Name:</td>
                <td class="TableFormInput" colspan="4">
                <font face="arial,helvetica" size="+1">test case </font>
                </td>
                <td class="TableFormInput" align="center">
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <tr>
                <tr id="cause_code_row" style="display: none;">
```

pls help.

I have added the code above.

Comment: Just writing out a structure doesn't tell us anything. Show some actual source code. Also, what do firebug and greasemonkey have to do anything with this?

Answer (score -1):

You need to run the script on the page that's loaded in the frame.

```
// @include     YourPage
// @include     IframedPage

if(window.location===IframedPage){
//Your code here...
}
```

If you need to pass info back and forth use GM_setValue or the equivalent.